# How to convert Path for scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

i need help in how to prepare a Linux path/dir for training scikit.
At the moment this works so far

```
db = get_db()
df = pd.read_sql_query(
    'SELECT Request,Used,Count FROM history where User = "john"', db)
print(df.head)
X = df[['Request','Count']]
y = df['Used']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)
model = LinearRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)
print("LinearRegression Training set score: {:.2f}".format(model.score(X_train, y_train)))
print("LinearRegression Test set score: {:.2f}".format(model.score(X_test, y_test))) 

#Output of print(df.head)
             Request       Used         Count
0            5400          3088         20   
1            6400          3500         20
```

Now i wanted to change the sql query and add to the result a path.

```
df = pd.read_sql_query(
  'SELECT Request,Used,Count,Path FROM history where User = "john"', db)
df['Path'] = df['Path'].str.split("/")
print(df.head)
X = df[['Request','Count','Path']]
y = df['Used']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)
...
#Output of print(df.head)
    #Output of print(df.head)
             Request       Used         Count    Path
0            5400          3088         20      [, home, john, testdir] 
1            6400          3500         20      [, home, john, blub]
```

How can convert df['PATH'] to be usable for scikit. Maybe a matrix like representaion with OneHotEnocder ?
Any help or tips would help me a lot.

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want the end-result of the `Path` column to look like? How many unique classes (home, john, testdir, blub, etc.) are there? A few or many? `MultiLabelBinarizer` seems like my gut response.

Comment: since the paths are user made, there could be some of them. There are only few main directory where a user can create his own dirs, e.g. /home,/tmp,/tmpdir. I noticed that some users tend to use similar naming schemes under different toplelvel dir. I was hoping to use that for better prediction, e.g. 
/tmp/john/abc/x1
/tmp/john/abc/x2
/tmp/john/abc/x3
/tmpdir/john/abc/x1
/tmpdir/john/abc/x2

And of course the path deep can vary a lot. So the length of a path column entry could be different
[, home, john, testdir] 
[, home, john, testdir, x1]

Answer (score 0):

i solved it this way.

```
dummy = df['Path'].str.split('/').apply(pd.Series).astype(str)
df = df.drop('Path', axis=1)
new_df = pd.concat([df, dummy], axis=1)
```

Depending on different Paths the dataframe can get very big. 
But it is sufficient to continue. I'll check df['Path'].str.extract() for better splitting the path.